# Is "as energetic as a stalk of whipped asparagus" an idiom?

Tags: idioms

I came across a sentence (shown below) and I'm wondering whether "as energetic as a stalk of whipped asparagus" is an idiom? I can't seem to find it in the dictionary, nor on the Internet.

> I came home from school the next day feeling as energetic as a stalk of whipped asparagus.

Comment: It's a metaphor, not an idiom. Moreover, unlike some metaphors, it's not a cliché (that is, it's not a commonly-used metaphor – at least, I've never heard it before. "Wet noodle" would be more cliché.)

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question?

Comment: @Evik: it **wasn't** my downvote, but I can think of a couple possible reasons: (1) It asks about an *idiom*, when describing a _metaphor_; (2) in a way, it answers its own question (if you can't find it on the Internet, or in a dictionary, then what would make it an idiom?). I elected to address these drawbacks with a _comment_; some other user may have done so with a _downvote_. Maybe the user wanted to remain anonymous. Maybe the user felt my comment already expressed his/her sentiments. Either way, both are fair and valid ways to give feedback.

Comment: @Ellie, in fairness to the author of this original phrase, could you please give us his/her name and the source? Thanks!

Comment: @JAM Sorry haven't been on here for a while! The original phrase is from a translated literary work "Mother's Books" by Daniel J. Bauer (the translator) published in a 2004 autumn issue of The Taipei Chinese PEN. The original work was written by Francis Sen-yao LIU in Chinese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there is a *[simile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile)* rather than a *[metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor)* or an *[idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom)*.

As noted in the wikipedia articles linked above,

> A simile is a figure of speech that directly compares two different things, usually by employing the words "like" or "as".

while

> A metaphor is a literary figure of speech that describes a subject by asserting that it is, on some point of comparison, the same as another otherwise unrelated object.

and

> An idiom ... is an expression, word, or phrase that has a figurative meaning that is comprehended [as] separate from the literal meaning or definition of the words of which it is made.